# Error adding modes in Processing

Tags: processing, socketexception

I recently downloaded Processing 2.2.1 and when I tried to add a programming mode through the menu on the right side, I got a `java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable` even though I can obviously connect to the internet, and an error message at the bottom of the "Add Modes" popup that said `could not find listof available contributions` instead of a list of the modes. I know that some modes can be manually downloaded and unzipped but I have yet to find a .zip file for the Python mode. Is it possible to fix this error so that I can download the modes through the GUI box and if so, how?

I had previously downloaded it for my Linux machine which runs Ubuntu and everything worked fine there but I was trying to migrate everything to my Windows 32 bit so I just re-downloaded it today for windows and got this error.

Comment: This problem is typical of when you don't have an internet connection. Maybe you're using an internet connection through a proxy?

Comment: That's what I thought initially but I checked and my internet was working fine, if a little slow. How do I check if I am using a connection through a Proxy?